# Microsoft graph authorization with grant type refresh_token not working for work account types

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, refresh-token

**TLDR: Refreshing token works for outlook account's, but I get error AADSTS65001 when I try to refresh the token of a work account.**

I am building a scheduling app (nodejs/react) where my users can integrate their outlook calendars so visitors can schedule events in their calendars. I am using @azure/msal-node for authentication.

**Msal config**

```
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: MICROSOFT_CREDENTIALS.CLIENT_ID,
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/',
        clientSecret: MICROSOFT_CREDENTIALS.CLIENT_SECRET
    }
};
Msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

**My app registration info:**

Supported account types: All Microsoft account users

Api permissions (all Delegated): Calendars.ReadWrite, offline_access, User.Read

**My app flow looks like this:**

1. User has in his profile a button to authenticate, gets redirected to url generated with msalClient.getAuthCodeUrl where he is asked for permissions,
2. After consenting, he gets redirected back with a code which I use to get the access token (msalClient.acquireTokenByCode),
3. I test I have access by calling '/me' endpoint and displaying account display name,
4. I get refresh token from msal token cache (getTokenCache().serialize() and get the right one with homeAccountId) and map it to the user,
5. Now that user has integrated outlook calendar, visitor should be able to schedule an event with him,
6. Visitor fills out event data,
7. Before creating the event, I get an access token by posting users refresh token to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' using the grant_type: 'refresh_token',
8. I post the event data to 'me/calendar/events' with the new access token.

This works perfectly with outlook.com accounts, but when I try it with a work account .onmicrosoft.com I get an error on step 7, when I try to refresh the token.. the error is:

**AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '[app id]' named '[app name]'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.**

I hope someone can help with this, I will gladly provide more information if needed!

Answer (score 1):

In your Azure Portal, activate **Allow user consent for apps**.

`Home -> Enterprise applications -> Your enterprise application -> User consent settings`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help!
Enterprise applications > Consent and permissions > User consent settings is already set to "Allow user consent for apps".

Comment: Can you try to grant admin consent for you application in the azure portal?

`App registrations -> Your app registration -> API permissions`

Comment: All of my API permissions are delegated, they don't require admin consent.

Comment: But as an administrator, you can still grant consent on behalf of the organization.

Comment: I tried granting the permissions for the default directory, it didn't fix the issue. When an admin of another org tries to authenticate, he gets a prompt for consent and an option to consent for the whole organization. That par (step 1 & step 2) is not the issue, I do get his permissions and do get the access token and I can create an event with it. The issue is getting a new refresh token with the old one, that part (step 7) succeeds for ordinary accounts and fails for work accounts.